# Ambiguous sentence

Tags: reading, structure

While I read the book "The Body: A Guide for Occupants", I found there an ambiguous senstence:

"We pass 800 million heartbeats after 25 years, and just keep on going for another fifty years and 1.6 billion heartbeats or so."

It is about human heartbeats for lifetime, so consequentially, After 75 years, total human heartbeats are 1.6 billion? OR 2.4 billion? Save me

Answer (score 2):

Before 25: 800e6/25yrs= 32e6/yr.
Assuming the heart rate remains the same after 25 years, the total is
(25 yrs + 50 yrs) * 32e6/yr = 2400e6 beats, or 2.4e9 = **2.4 billion**.

The statement "keep going on" refers to the additional time and the additional beats after age 25.